# What's the minimum stat value needed to maximize your stats by the time you reach 9 star level?

Tags: theatrhythm-final-bar-line

I'm trying to figure out how many of my items I need to spend on a level 99 character to be able to max out all their stats at 9 stars while not wasting them. Assuming 9999 is max HP and 999 is for the rest.

What's the minimum stat value needed to be able to max stats by the time I reach 9 star level?

Considering each star level adds to all stats (+50 I've seen so far at 1 star), does it scale up further on? If it's +50 all the way, then it would suggest ~550 (+450 from star levels) but is that it?

Are there other points where you can gain stats other than leveling up? I've seen you can gain +1 point for all your stats apparently at random after completing a song.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having gained some star levels, it appears the values you gain are fixed per star level. There are 9 star levels and for every start, you gain:

- 300 HP
- 50 Strength
- 50 Magic
- 50 Spirit
- 50 Agility
- 50 Luck

With the max stat of 999 for all but HP which is 9999, you will need to gain up to this many points by the time you reach level 99 and every star level:

[image: table]

If you're at that level and you have more points in a particular stat, then you should stop spending any more items on that character for that stat.